# GraphQL mutation, parameters / variables objects (with dot notation)

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a Graphql Mutation like this:

*gql query*:

```
mutation UpdateMother($mother_id: ID!, $child_name: String!) {
  updateMother(
    mother: {
      id: $id
      child: {
        name: $child_name
      }
    }
  )
}
```

It works good, but I need to use `$child.name` instead of `$child_name`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call this mutation like

```
mutate({
  variables: {
    mother_id: mother.id,
    child_name: child.name
  }
})
  .then(() => {})
  .catch(() => {})
```

Also note that you're defining $mother_id as an input, and using $id in the 4th line. You should be using something like:

```
mutation UpdateMother($mother_id: ID!, $child_name: String!) {
  updateMother(
    mother: {
      id: $mother_id
      child: {
        name: $child_name
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: This is what I do in my variables. What I was wondering is if there is a way to handle this directly in mutation query and not in variables. I'm thinking to forms, in that way I could use: `...data` only.

Comment: The only way you can do that is if your `data` variable is composed by keys with the exact variable names in the `.gql`.

In this case, you would have to have `data = { mother_id: '1', child_name: 2 }` to use `mutate({ variables: { ...data }})`